# How do I manipulate the contents of a stat() struct?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, system-calls, stat

I have a stat struct, and I'm looking for a way to get data out of it to be manipulated. The program will successfully run and print the desired st_mtime value, but including either of the "seg-fault" lines below causes a segmentation fault in runtime.

```
        struct stat buf;
        time_t time_m;
        time_t sys_time = time(0);
        if(stat(sub_dirp->d_name,&buf)==0)
                 {
                     //time_m = buf.st_mtime;                                     //seg-fault
                     //double since_last = (difftime(sys_time, buf.st_mtime)/60); //seg-fault
                     printf("%d ", (int)buf.st_mtime);                          //This works.
                 }
```

Both lines are attempting to manipulate the `buf.st_mtime` value in some way.

I've had a hard time finding any examples of the usage of stat() that do anything other than print its contents, which makes me wonder if it's even possible.

So my question is, if it is possible, what am I missing?

P.S. I do wish to keep `st_mtime` in the Unix timestamp format to make it easier to manipulate.

Edit: After realizing that `st_mtime` is itself its own struct (timespec), how can I access the `st_mtime.tv_sec` member?

The compiler doesn't like `buf.st_mtime.tv_sec` one bit.

[compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ag3HM.png)

Comment: Reading the `struct stat` as you are should not cause a segfault. However, treating a `struct timespec` as a `time_t` might do it...

Comment: Ergh, I had to look it up. So `time_t` is a macro resolving to a `time_t`, equal to `st_mtim.tv_sec`. So `difftime` should work on it without problem...

Comment: About [time_t](https://koor.fr/C/ctime/time_t.wp) definition.

Comment: I still don't see how this could possibly have caused a segfault, unless there was some other bug in your program.  Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Please post your compiler error as text, not as a link to an image.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who was stumped by this, I ended up achieving my desired result by creating a timespec struct:

```
struct timespec tspec;
```

This subsequently allowed me to make these two assignments:

```
tspec.tv_sec = buf.st_mtime;
time_t time_m = tspec.tv_sec; //tv_sec is of type time_t
```

Then I can manipulate time_m however I please.
Although I must admit I'm still not sure why you can't assign `time_m` directly to `buf.st_mtime` if doing it with a "middleman" works just fine.

Comment: I wouldn’t say I was stumped. I couldn’t reproduce your problem. But glad you got it sorted.